# How do I look up which package brought a particular command?

Tags: package-management

For example, there is a command "send_arp", I'm not sure which package should I uninstall if I want to remove it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can determine the file name for a command line utility using the `which` command.  For example, we can look up the path of the `ls` command:

```
$ which ls
/bin/ls
```

With that information, you can find out which package owns the file using `dpkg`:

```
$ dpkg -S /bin/ls
coreutils: /bin/ls
```

That tells us that `ls` is provided by the `coreutils` package.

Comment: To make a one-liner out of this, you could simply run `dpkg -S $(which ls)`, and of course, don't forget to substitute `ls` for the actual command being queried.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to James's post you can also do this on-line: [send-arp](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=natty&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=send_arp). That way you can find not only the package but also all the dependencies (if there are any): [cluster-agents](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/cluster-agents)